# Scroll the screen to bottom without scrollview and without ID and without firstChild android-espresso automation

Tags: android-espresso

I want to scroll to bottom of current screen displayed, but

1. Application don't have any ScrollView. Application have HorizontalScrollView but it is out of context.
2. Using onView, TableLayout with ID in the screen. But it throws error with matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
3. Using onView, by getting firstChild() but still it throws error with cannot perform operation, Error performing 'scroll to' on view 'with first child view of type parentMatcher'.
4. Tried onData(hasToString(startsWith(). But it throws error with matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
5. Tried other ways like getting current Monitor and Activity but still didn't work.

Comment: not enough info in your question to answer you. Post the layout file or Espresso stacktrace.

Comment: Yeah a view hierarchy would help clarify things. Also what do you mean by `out of context`? Do you mean the view has been detached, or it lives in a different process?

Comment: +------>LinearLayout
+------->GridView
+-------->LinearLayout
+--------->TextView
+--------->TableLayout
+---------->LinearLayout Row 1
+----------->LinearLayout Row 1
+------------>TextView
+------------>TextView
+------------>TextView

Same structure for ROW 2, ROW 3 and ROW 4. Trying to scroll to ROW 3 or End of Window will also work.

Answer (score 8):

OK, what I can suggest, based on scanty information in your question:

1. Easy approach (but not fully correct) - just swipe up int the GridView to go to its bottom:

   ```
   onView(withId(R.id.GridView_Id)).perform(swipeUp());
   ```
2. Easy approach:

   ```
   onData(instanceOf(Object_in_the_ROW.class))
       .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.GridView_Id))
       .atPosition(2)  //position # can very if you have header or not
       .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
       .perform(click());  //or any other action, or no action
   ```
3. Approach I prefer:

   ```
   onData(withROWText("unique_text_in_ROW3"))
       .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.GridView_Id))
       .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
       .perform(click());
   ```

where withRowText() is the custom matcher to match specific text in the ROW3, something like:

```
public static Matcher<Object> withRowText(String expectedText) {
    Checks.checkNotNull(expectedText);
    return withRowText(equalTo(expectedText));
}

public static Matcher<Object> withRowText(final Matcher<String> itemTextMatcher) {
    Checks.checkNotNull(itemTextMatcher);
    return new BoundedMatcher<Object, ROWObject>(ROWObject.class) {
        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(ROWObject rowObject) {
            return itemTextMatcher.matches(rowObject.text);
        }

        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with rowObject: ");
            itemTextMatcher.describeTo(description);
        }
    };
}
```

BTW, "GridView is a ViewGroup that displays items in a two-dimensional, **scrollable** grid."

Comment: 2nd approach must work for you perfectly as well and each row item must represent the same class, for example you have a 10 elements in the grid which represent goods you are interesting in, so, each one represents class Goods (instanceOf(Goods.class)). Don't use onView() it is not developed to operate on adapters, use onData() instead.

Comment: I tried that onData(instanceOf(MyClass.class)).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.grid)).atPosition(2) //TableLayput .check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(swipeUp()); also tried onData(instanceOf(MyClass.class)).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.grid)).atPosition(2) //TableLayput .check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(scrollTo()); but in both cases it is throwing PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'with id: com.app.mobile:id/grid'. Thank you for your help as I am stuck in this issue since many days.